# Transforms postgres db data to encode html special characters

Tags: html, postgresql, transform, special-characters, html-entities

I have converted the SR27 data (food nutrition data from the USDA) into a postgres database, but some of the values have quotation marks and other characters in them. I'd like to transform these to the encoded format (e.g. `&` becomes `&amp;`). That is the best way to store any HTML characters right?

Is there a way to transform the entire DB? Multiple tables with multiple columns?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to perform that conversion at the edge of your application? Say when you're building an HTML page?

Comment: Maybe that is the best way. I'm not sure though. That's one reason why I asked if that is the best way to store them. Do you know what standard is?

Comment: Store text as text and deal with encoding issues at the edges. No other approach makes sense to me.